# While loop incrementer not functioning properly

Tags: python, while-loop, iteration, increment

Right now, my code is correctly spitting out the first game (identified by start_id) in games. I am trying to increment in the bottom two lines, but the while loop doesn't seem to read the fact that I'm incrementing. So the input of this with start_id 800 and end_id 802 is just the information from 800, for some reason.

Am I using the incrementers correctly? Should I be initializing one of i or start_id elsewhere?

```
games = console(start_id, end_id)
final_output = []

while start_id < (end_id + 1):
    single_game = []
    i = 0
    game_id = games[i][0] 
    time_entries = games[i][1][2][0]
    play_entries = games[i][1][2][1]
    score_entries = games[i][1][2][2]
    team_entries = games[i][1][2][3]
    bovada = games[i][1][0][0][0]
    at_capacity = games[i][1][0][1]
    idisagree_yetrespect_thatcall = games[i][1][0][2][0]
    imsailingaway = games[i][1][1][0][0]
    homeiswheretheheartis = games[i][1][1][1][0]

    zipper = zip(time_entries, play_entries, score_entries, team_entries)

    for play_by_play in zipper:
        single_game.append(game_id)
        single_game.append(play_by_play)
        single_game.append(bovada)
        single_game.append(at_capacity)
        single_game.append(idisagree_yetrespect_thatcall)
        single_game.append(imsailingaway)
        single_game.append(homeiswheretheheartis)

    start_id += 1
    i += 1
    final_output.append(single_game)
return final_output
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you initialize the increment-er `i` inside the `while` loop so every time your loop iterates `i` is reset to zero.

Try changing it to:

```
i = 0
while start_id < (end_id + 1):
    ...
```